# Recursion and First-Order-Logic

Tags: first-order-logic, recursion

I have the following setup. $<>$ is a sequence. $()$ is a tuple.

$A_1 = < B_1, B_3 >$
where 
$B_1 = < C_2, C_3, C_4 >$ and $B_3 = < C_5 > $

So $A_1 = << C_2,C_3,C_4 >, < C_5 >>$

$C$ is a tuple of the form $(C_{index}, 1)$. $B$ is a sequence of $C$'s.

I want to write a recursion that takes an $A$, say $A_1$, and returns

(1) the number of $B$'s in $A$ (in the example above, this is 2)

(2) the number of $C$'s in $A$ (in the example above, this is 4)

(3) to flatten the sequence of $C$'s in $A$ (in the example above, you should get a sequence of $<C_2,C_3,C_4,C_5>$.

In my book they have an example, which is what I am trying to use here.

Entry == Date x Course x Location x Professor x N (N = natural number = number of students)

Table == seq Entry

To write the recursive function of the total number of students attending all courses we say:
$\forall$ x : Entry; k : seq Entry $\bullet$ total (<>) = 0 $\land$ total (< x > ^ k) = x.5 + total(k)
This makes sense but in this case we simply have this structure: 
$x = < (tuple1), (tuple2)... >$ so x.5 can be simply extracted.

My ideas so far:
(1) Won't the cardinality of the set resolve this? 
(2) Typically I use x.2 to identify the second element of the tuple and then recurse over it but this won't work here.
(3) Not sure how to do this.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

For 1: Sequences are not the same as sets, so while the basic idea of taking the cardinality is good, technically it's not something you apply to a sequence. However, what the idea *does* correspond to, is the *length* of a sequence. Also, I thought you had to provide a recursive function?  So how about:

$Length(<>)=0$

$Length(<B|S>) = 1+Length(S)$

(in here, $<B|S>$ means a sequence whose first entry is $B$, and where the rest of the sequence is sequence $S$. So, for example, if $S = <1,2,3,4>$, then $S= <1|<2,3,4>>$ (this is standard notation in LISP or PROLOG))

For 2: How about:

$Length2(<>)=0$

$Length2(<B|S>) = Length(B)+Length2(S)$

For 3:

$Flatten(<>) = <>$

$Flatten(<B|S>) = Concat(B,Flatten(S))$

where

$Concat(<>,S) = S$

$Concat(<C|B>,S) = <C|Concat(B,S)>$

Note: using the $Flatten$ function, you can do the $Length2$ function also as follows:

$Length2(S) = Length(Flatten(S))$

Comment: I have not seen the B|S notation before. Is there a document on this where I can read up more? Suppose x = <<seq1>,<seq2>,<seq3>>. I am confused why x.3 for example is used to select the 3rd element of a tuple in a sequence, but this cannot be applied to a sequence in a sequence. x.3 would select the third sequence in a sequence, correct? Then you would need another iteration to select the 2nd element, for example, of the tuples in the sequence selected?

Comment: Any further comments on this please?

Comment: I am understanding the notation above now but not following how/why it works. An example would really help please! I would love to know how to provide the Length2(S)=Length(Flatten(S)) piece also as I am curious now (I can see it will work but wondering how to show this).

Comment: forgot to quote you. I went through this again and understood the base case (empty sequence). However, I am still struggling how you derived it. I am trying to do the same for other structures (like the one updated in the initial post) so it would be good to understand the method also. Thanks!

Comment: Bram28 I managed to solve it using the above. I didn't realise Concat was the same as | for sequences really but once I understood this, the rest followed. :)

Comment: @Iseactuary That's good to hear! Thanks for letting me know and I am glad I could provide some help :)